# fragments in viewpager get recycled and not reloaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, recycle, fragment-lifecycle

I have fragments in a viewpager. The viewpager loads the fragments one index forward and one index behind the current index.

The user can scroll past the viewpager, and this uses more memory as other image objects are processed in other parts of the layout. When they scroll back up to the viewpager, the index forward may not display anything because the entire fragment got recycled (or something). When the user scrolls left a few times in the viewpager and back the other way again, then the missing fragments get redrawn properly.

Is there some fragment lifecycle event I can detect to ensure that it never displays an empty version? Like a way to force the fragment to reload in case its adapter recycled it

Comment: If fragment is recycled, before showing again it's recreated and all lifecycle events are called

Comment: @Jedil that is the expected behavior..... but I'm experiencing something else with my viewpager, sometimes.

Comment: So you are doing something wrong? Post code so i will try to help.